# htaccess rewrute rules for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

I added *.domain.com. to my bind so after that i can run all subdomains which link to my main homepage so bleble.domain.com opens main page domain.com

My main goal is to link {subdomain_name}.domain.com to /index.php?/member/{subdomain_name} using htaccess and without redirect 301

So far i have got something like that but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ /index.php?/member/$1 [L,P]

# codeigniter
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^core.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I receive such an error

```
Not Found
The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your subdomains rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/member/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/member/%2/$1 [L]
```

Your condition is correct, you want to match against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable. Grouping the subdomain, `([a-z0-9-]+)`, you can backreference it in your `RewriteRule` by using `%2` (`%1` would reference the "www.").

The `$1` backreference is to the `(.*)`, because you want to also be able to match a blank URI. This way, if you go to `http://subdomain.domain.com/` in your browser, it gets served the content at `/index.php?/member/subdomain/`, and if you go to `http://subdomain.domain.com/path/to/a/file` you get the content at `/index.php?/member/subdomain/path/to/a/file`.

You also want to lose the `P` flag, since you're not going to need any proxying.

Comment: This is what i get: `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@escard.pl and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: @TestTest Sorry, forgot to add a condition to stop looping: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/member/`

Comment: I appreciate that, evrything works fine now. :) I see you are really good :) i didn't write that there are too many connections -> apache log ( Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error ) and you corrected RewriteRules properly